# Capturing all function and system calls from a Windows executable

Tags: trace

Apologies if this is a noob question.

I have an issue with a Windows application and I am trying to trace exactly what system calls it might be making (it's logs claim it is making HTTP calls but wire traces show no egress traffic). I have looked at Sysinternals procmon and it has some stack tracing capability but only on the events that it captures (registry, network and file activity). I have looked at Windows Performance Recorder and [`Windbg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) with time-travel. Are either o these 'sane' approaches?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.